# How to set my dummy SQL row as the top row?

Tags: sql

I'm creating an SQL query that has a dummy row and I want it as the top row to be used as a default value in a program I'm developing.

This is the query I have so far:

```
Select '[Select Project]' as [Project] 
union all 
select [Project] from [IOT].[dbo].[Project] order by [Project] desc
```

What I want is the data to arrange as:

```
------------------
|     Project    |
------------------
|[Select Project]|
|     T00002     |
|     T00001     |
------------------
```

But instead I get:

```
------------------
|     Project    |
------------------
|     T00002     |
|     T00001     |
|[Select Project]|
------------------
```

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to introduce an "ordering" (or sequence) column - something like this:

```
Select '[Select Project]' as [Project], 0 as roworder
union all 
select [Project], 1 as roworder
from [IOT].[dbo].[Project] 
order by roworder, [Project] desc
```

Comment: Quarantine's made my logic a little rusty